# AWS Device Farm send requests to server

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, python-requests, aws-device-farm

I struggle with an issue for a few days/weeks now and decided to ask the community help. 
I use AWS device farm to run my automation tests. For the test framework I use Appium + Python.
The app tested has mobile native clients and a web app. I'm using the requests library from Python to send requests to the web app in order to find out if the info sent from the mobile clients is ok.

On local environment everything works. But on AWS Host I receive the following error when `r = session.get(self.url)` is executed:

> ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='my_adress', port=myPort): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to my address timed out.
>   (connect timeout=100)'))

More info:
The server is running on another AWS Host inside a private network, but with public subnet available.

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: Can you connect to the url in question? It looks like your devices can't access that box either because there is no network path(no route) which can take them there or there is a firewall(AWS Security Group and/or ACL) blocking them.

Comment: @Raf answer helped. Seemed that was an AWS Security group issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

1. You mentioned that your expected Appium server is on another AWS host. Assuming you did not mean AWS Device Farm instance to which the device is connected when you said AWS host, this will be a case of VPC support. In this case today VPC support is not in place. We are looking at how to support it though.
2. Device Farm has its own instance of Appium server that the tests are run against. This is the same as the Appium that you would have run locally when the device is also connected to the same machine and not on another host.
3. If you want to use the Device Farm Appium server you should use http://127.0.0.1/4723/wdhub as the url of the server.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, I have a use case where I wrote a custom nodeJS HTTP server, that the app is communicating with. This service is started as part of the device farm's script. However, the app cannot reach the HTTP server (I am even forwarding the host IPv4 to the app). Is this something that should work? Thx in advance! :)